# Method accessible only for the outside?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is it possible to have method have methods that are only callable externally and never callable internally?  If so how?

```
Public Class Foo
  Public Sub New()
    Bar ' Should fail to compile as Bar is only accessible externally.'
  End Class
  Public External Sub Bar()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm curious: What do you need that for?

Comment: It must be possible as the Constructor can't be access internally. (Not that I'm saying that you should, but you can't).

Comment: You _can_ access the constructor, just not like a method. Same from inside as from outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible in C# or VB. Why would you *want* to do that anyway? Why would you "trust" the code within the class *less* than the code outside it?

Comment: Maybe he is just curious. Personally I wondered the same thing when I first learned about access modifiers several years ago (granted, I realized about a second later that such a feature would be useless).

Comment: See the comment and link I post below

Comment: Another what if methods where Non-Recursive by default, and you add to add an attribute to explicitly allow it.

Comment: @Adam: Why would you not just make it clear within the code? Why would you need the compiler to enforce this?

Comment: @Jon, I think it could be useful when you implement an Adapter or Wrapper class: such modifier will prevent you from calling recursively the same method (stackoverflow exeption), instead of the wrapped one.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to have method have methods that are only callable externally and never callable internally? If so how?

No, this is not possible to stop at compile-time (you *could* walk the stack at run time, but that smells horrible).

Can you explain why you want this?

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly implement an interface, the implementation requires a cast; Doesn't sound like exactly what you want, but it may work in a pinch?  But then, maybe it would be better to outline *why* you are asking for this, there probably is a better overall approach...

```
public class Foo : IBar
{
    void IBar.Bar() {}

    void AMethod() { 
        Bar(); // Compile Failure
        ((IBar)this).Bar(); // No failure
    }
 }
```

Note that this requires the code outside to also reference the object as an IBar, that may make it even less desirable as a solution for you.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is possible in an easy way, generally is the other way round, you want to use something internally and prevent the consumers to call internal things. Internally, as the designer of the class, you know how things work and you do not need to be prevented to access certain methods.

the designer/coder of the class will probably have written the internal methods and the public ones as well so he/she will know what should not be called from inside... if it makes sense at all... if you have a good design I kind of doubt.

Comment: It just out of curiosity as you cane have internal only ones.

Comment: I wanted to make the call-ability more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you would want to do this?  Ever?

But no, in short, you cannot.  YOU are the developer, so just make sure you never call it.

Now you COULD attempt force it to fail at run time:

```
public void MyExternalOnlyMethod(object sender) 
{
    if(sender==this) throw new ICantCallMeException();
}
```

Of course you then have to ensure your internal method calls to this method (which you shouldn't write to begin with) have to send "this" as sender...

But like the others said...

**Why???**

About as close as you'll ever get is using abstract methods, but that's just for requiring that a derived class implement certain functionality that you yourself wont in your class.

Comment: This is still callable from other methods inside the object.

Comment: Oh you mean the method would/could be the sender, I suppose?

Comment: See [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/237374-understanding-events-with-the-crying-baby-example). Suppose I want to prevent self feeding baby.

Comment: @Adam: Then you just don't call the method from within that code. Code within a class is trusted not to screw up.

Comment: @Jon Skeet  I think it would make screwing up even harder.

Comment: @Adam: But it would be easy to screw up from *every other class*? Sorry, it just doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Adam: What are you trying to show me from the link?  The more I read your responses the less I think you actually read mine.

Comment: @The Evil Greebo: I read them. If you examine the code of The class baby, you'll see that baby is handling it's own public Crying event. So in theory and in (bad) practice coukd raise the event again. Recursive events. If it were possible mark the event as external only callable, it would stop this.